# imshow in Octave under OSX 10.9.5 shows the image with the y-axis inverted

Tags: macos, octave, imshow

According to the Octave help:

```
 The origin (0, 0) for images is located in the
 upper left.  For ordinary plots, the origin is located in the lower
 left.  Octave handles this inversion by plotting the data normally,
 and then reversing the direction of the y-axis by setting the
 'ydir' property to "reverse".
```

However, imshow is showing the image with the origin in the lower left corner, and thus the image is mirrored vertically.

Is this a sign of a bad installation, an undocumented change, or?

Is there any way to change this so that it is not necessary to reverse the Y-axis every time?

Thank you.

Comment: does get(gca, "ydir") return "reverse"? What graphics_toolkit are you using? Which GNU Octave version? Installed using fink, macports, homebrew?

Comment: running under Windows, Octave 4.0.0, image package 2.4.1.  under all three graphics_toolkit options (qt, fltk, & gnuplot) , imshow puts the array origin value (the row=1, col=1 entry) in the upper left of the displayed image. also, get(gca,'ydir') does show reverse for all three. So if there is an issue, it seems isolated to OSX, your version, or similar.

Comment: I have version 4.0.0 installed with homebrew. I'm using X11, and get(gca, "ydir") returns "reverse". The packages I have installed are:

     control  |   3.0.0 
     general  |   2.0.0
       image  |   2.4.1
      signal  |   1.3.2

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Rearranging-Matrices.html
I have also had this problem and the only way I have found to solve it is to flip the matrix. If your image is mirrored vertically, use the command fliplr(A), which will mirror matrix A.

Comment: Thank you, that worked, but to solve the vertical mirror I had to use flipud(A);